# Why is null almost always passed to RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

Nearly every example of WebRTC I've seen on the Internet involves creating a `RTCPeerConnection` with a single parameter of `null`.  [The spec calls for two parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) to be passed: an ICE server configuration and your media constraints.

I've noticed that technically everything still works if the two requests are coming from the same router when you pass `null` (for instance, `var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);`).  I'm not sure it works cross-network.  Can someone shed some more light here as to what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Nearly every example of WebRTC I've seen on the Internet involves creating a RTCPeerConnection with a single parameter of null.

I guess for the examples, most of the time it is assumed that you're on the same computer. So you don't really need any iceServers. (And the examples don't want to provide you with a "free" stun-server/turn-server?)

> I've noticed that technically everything still works if the two requests are coming from the same router when you pass null.

This won't be the case if the clients are not on the same network. Because without a stun server (passed through the iceServers config) the clients have no way of getting their server reflexive addresses.

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments by [@syno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2782676/syno):

At the moment, one of the "security" issues with webRTC is that the STUN and TURN server configs are passed as clear text when creating the peer connection. Anybody can look at the JavaScript code and use your servers. This is why using a TURN server with a REST API (code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/wiki/turnserver) to have a temporary "timestamp" is necessary to limit the usage from unwanted users. Adding all this complexity in a simple demo is not wanted when the purpose is to learn or show the basic concept of webRTC

Comment: I would also add that at the moment, one of the "security" issues with webRTC is that the STUN and TURN server configs are passed as clear text when creating the peer connection. Anybody can look at the JavaScript code and use your servers. This is why using a TURN server with a REST API (https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/wiki/turnserver) to have a temporary "timestamp" is necessary to limit the usage from unwanted users. Adding all this complexity in a simple demo is not wanted when the purpose is to learn or show the basic concept of webRTC.